# wordpress //bloginfo\\ function not echoing output on parts of the pages

Tags: wordpress

im having a bit of a problem with `php bloginfo` ive never had before with with wordpress....not sure how to go about it.

normally i use `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/rest of link 4 img here`

but for some reason now it doesn't work. when i view source, its not echoing out the link like its supposed to and it just comes out as `"src="/images/pic name here"`

ive tried using `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');` etc

i even saw some post here on SO that tried to somehow concatenate the get_bloginfo with the link like this

And again, the weird thing is that i define my external assets the same way.
like this for example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts_n_css/css/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

any ideas as to whats going on? Thanks in advanced.

EDIT*** So if you take a look at this site im working on, http://www.islandlivingpatio.com/?page_id=48 the images dont load up. When i inspect with FireBug, it says "failed to load given url"
but the thing works on my local host.

This is what the sites image and the url it goes to look like.

```
<a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url');?>/?page_id=775"><img src="<?php bloginfo("template_directory");?>/images/Lynx.gif" alt="castandtubular"/></a>
```

And again, theY DO work on my local machine. When you click that images alt tag(since its the only thing showing up" then the next page also fails to load the images.

Any ideas as to whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `get_bloginfo('template_directory')` like so:

```
<img src="<?php get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/your-img-here.jpg" />
```

Comment: Hello ryan thanks for replying. ive tried that and no good. I literally copied/paste and added my image name and only the alt tag comes up. Upon checking again, this is the output of that tag  src="/dummy-firstpage-pic.jpg" title=""> everything thats supposed to come RIGHT infront of that src never appears

Comment: Could you edit your initial question with some more of the code you are using?

Comment: Hello again, i edited the question with an example as to whats going on and where with a link aswell for you to see.

Comment: It looks like your `img` tag is looking for the image correctly in your theme directory: `<img src="http://www.islandlivingpatio.com/wp-content/themes/islandlivingpatiocustom/images/double-sideburner.jpg" alt="castandtubular" title="">`

Are you sure that the double-sideburner.jpg file is in your images folder of your template directory on your server?

Comment: the problem i found(and dont as me how because im clueless lol) is that SOMEHOW, the file permissions were switched on upload. so the files i was having problems with were all "owner read only" hence them appearing in code but not shown on the page........again, i dont know how. i had to manually go in and change the file permissions for each.  trying to research now. Thanks for your help. ill mark yours as the "it" response since it did work.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using get_bloginfo(), you have to actually echo the output like so:

```
<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>
```

Note the "echo" before "get_bloginfo()".

Comment: but isnt "bloginfo()" supposed to echo out the information by itself? because ive always used it in this manner and never had a problem.....

Comment: "bloginfo()" goes echo the info by itself. It's possible that there's something else going on in your code that's preventing bloginfo() from echoing the requested value. Can you share more of your code in your original question?

Comment: Hello there, i edited my question as requested to show whats going on also provided a link so you can see whats going on and the message i get from firebug